# Is there any compiler flag to force undefined behavior for signed integer overflow?

Tags: rust

I’m writing a graph algorithm that needs to be super fast. Is there any compiler flag to force undefined behavior for signed integer overflow like C? Or any other flags to force more undefined behavior? If not, has anyone benchmarked the speed difference?

Comment: Why would you possibly want that?! If you want a panic on overflow use checked_add etc.

Comment: You don't want undefined behavoir because it is undefined! Duh. What you probably want is `wrapping_add`.

Comment: Btw: safe rust has always defined behavoir.

Comment: *"If not, has anyone benchmarked the speed difference?"* This would be probably your job. Don't optimize blindly and especially not in favor of UB. Well, this question is awkward in many ways :| Why would anyone ever want UB?

Comment: Graph algorithms are generally memory bound, not arithmetic bound. However, `std::intrinsics::assume` might help.

Comment: My team writes scientific codes in C, C++ and Fortran. I'm trying to convince them to try Rust but I need to know what Rust guarantees and how to get around it.

Comment: Yes Veedrac is absolutely right that graph algorithms are memory bound. But we have some cache-friendly tricks.

Answer (score 3):

Integer overflow in Rust never triggers undefined behaviour, in contrast to C. When compiling in debug mode, arithmetic operations check for overflow and panic, but in release mode there are no checks. The behaviour can be controlled by passing the flag `-C overflow-checks=yes` to `rustc`.

More generally, you should make sure to use release builds if performance matters. If you only want to target a specific CPU, you can use `-C target-cpu=val`, e.g. `-C target-cpu=native` to optimise for the current CPU. And of course you need to profile your code to figure out what to optimise.

Comment: It seems like that could be it! I was thinking about "undoing" -fwrapv in GCC for example.